# Textbox display undefined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Query1 to retrieve the data from firebase database and display on the dropdownlist. Comfirm function is to get the dropdownlist value and match with the database then display the database data into textbox. But the textboxes display undefined.

```js
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('facility');
var query1 = firebaseRef.orderByKey();
query1.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var facrecord1 = snapshot.val();
    console.log(facrecord1.schedulename);     
    $("#select_schedule").append("<option>"+ facrecord1.schedulename +"</option>" );     
});

function comfirm(){     
    var ds = document.getElementById("select_schedule");      
    var select_update = ds.options[ds.selectedIndex].value;      
    window.alert(select_update);      
  
    var match_query = firebaseRef.orderByChild('schedulename').equalTo(select_update);
    match_query.once('value',function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(child){
            var up = document.getElementById("update_name").value = snapshot.val().schedulename;
            var uf = document.getElementById("update_fees").value = snapshot.val().fees;       
        })  
    });
}
```

```html
<label style="color: #f2f2f2">Schedule</label> <br/>
<select id="select_schedule">

</select>
<br/>
<button onclick="comfirm()" id="comfirm">Comfirm</button>

<label style="color: #f2f2f2">Schedule Name</label> <br/>
<input type ="text" id="update_name" name="update_name" />


<label style="color: #f2f2f2">Fees</label><br/>
<input type="number" name="update_fees" id="update_fees" min="1" />
```

My database

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
match_query.once('value',function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(child){
        var up = document.getElementById("update_name").value = snapshot.val().schedulename;
        var uf = document.getElementById("update_fees").value = snapshot.val().fees;                
    })      
});
```

into this:

```
match_query.once('value',function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(child){
        var up = document.getElementById("update_name").value = child.val().schedulename;
        var uf = document.getElementById("update_fees").value = child.val().fees;               
    })      
});
```

since the `ForEach` is iterating inside the children nodes then you need to use, `child.val().schedulename` to be able to access these nodes.

Comment: No problem,  happy coding!